# Will NodeJS Block Concurrent Calls to Async Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have an async function that will cache the result of an expensive port scan for RTSP cameras. Several workers created using setInterval might be calling this function around the same time. I'm wondering will all workers wait until the first promise is resolved and then get the cached result or will each worker start another scan?

```js
/**
 * Get either the cached rstp scan or perform a new one.
 * @param port: port number being scanned
 */
export const getRtspCached = async (port: number): Promise<RstpAddr[]> => {
    const key = port.toString()
    const cached = await rtspCache.getItem<RstpAddr[]>(key)

    if (cached) {
        return cached
    }

    return getRtspForceScan(port)
}
```

Comment: no, it will stack them up until you fill your cache when one resolves, likely your want to implement a job queue that only a single worker runs the job and spawn off other workers to do the work / scan the ports, reporting back to the original job

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I might have to introduce a lock like this [async-mutex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-mutex).